# Alarm Clock app error

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public void pickTimeHandler(View target) {
    Toast.makeText(Alarms1.this, "in  PickTimehandler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showDialog(0);
```

where you see Alarm1.this is always an error in all of my code that says
No enclosing instance of the type Alarms1 is accessible in scope

Comment: Please show us your whole class. Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: Ok if you can't post the full code (it must be hundreds or thousands of lines).. Can you just post the structure of the classes on here? For example show the class declaration (public class YourClass) and then show any relevant inner class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You would write Alarms1.this if that is the name of the enclosing class

What is the name of the class this is in? Use that name.

Example:

```
public class Alarms1 {    
   public void pickTimeHandler(View target) {
     //code below would work, you could also just write "this" instead of "Alarms1.this"
    Toast.makeText(Alarms1.this, "in  PickTimehandler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showDialog(0);
  }
}
```

You only need to qualify the *this* value with the name of the class if it is made from an inner class.

Here is an example of when you need to qualify what "this" parameter you are using:

```
public class Alarms1 {
   public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_alarm);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Alarms1.this, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });
   }
}
```

The difference is that in the above code in the second example you are creating an anonymous inner class when you put

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
          // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

And from within that code if you wrote `this` the java compiler/runtime would think you were referring to the instance of the inner class (as opposed to the Alarms1).

--- UPDATE ---

Given the code you sent me I came up with this:

package com.example;

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    public void pickTimeHandler(View target) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "in  PickTimehandler",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showDialog(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "- onCreateDialog(ID_TIMEPICKER) -",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        OnTimeSetListener theTimeSetListener = null;
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                theTimeSetListener,
                hour, minute, false);
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener theTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
            String time = "User picked Hour: " + String.valueOf(hour) + "\n"
                    + "Minute: " + String.valueOf(minute);
            Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this, time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int theHour = hour;
            int theMinute = minute;

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
            alarmIntent.putExtra("nel.example.alarms1", "My message");
            Object pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmActivity.this, 0,
                    alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar AlarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            AlarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            AlarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, theHour); // set user selection
            AlarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, theMinute); // set user selection
            AlarmCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                    (PendingIntent) pendingAlarmIntent);
        }
    };

}
```

The changes I made are:

1. Renamed class form myMenu to AlarmActivity (The class has nothing to do with a menu, it is an alarm isn't it). Also classs names should start with a capital letter.
2. PendingIntent.getService need a context. This is EXACTLY the problem I described in my original solution. An Activity is a subclass of Context, which means you can pass an actvity to PendingIntent.getService in the first parameter. However when you created that inner class:

   private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener theTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

The code within that no longer was an Activity, it was a TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener. You need to pass myMenu.this as the first parameter (or in my case, since I renamed your class to AlarmActivity, you would pass AlarmActivity.this). The same thing goes with Toasts that you create within an inner class.

I highly suggest you stop what you are doing and go learn java before continuing android development. Read a book, follow online tutorials, etc. But if you just dive into android without understanding java you will have a load of problems.

Comment: oh so i put this in my alarams1 java?

Comment: I don't know where you should put it, that is up to you to decide (I didn't build the program). More than likely you should just change Alarms1.this to this

Comment: the method getService(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){}, int, Intent, int)

Comment: see my comment above (in your main post)

Comment: when i try to add the full code on stackoverflow it gives me errors

Comment: maybe you can give me your email i can send you the code or i can just type in comment